# Find the next multiple of a number

Tags: perl, int, division

I want to find (given a number that could be a float) how to find the next multiple of 60.
I am doing the following which works:

```
my $nextMultiple = int($input/$constant);                                                                                                                                         
$nextMultiple = ((int($nextMultiple/60)) * 60);                                                                                                                                   
$nextMultiple += 60;
```

I actually add 60 in the last line on purpose. Is there a better way for this?

Comment: What value do you want if the number is already a multiple of 60?

Comment: Hmm, XY-problem? Need to round to the nearest minute?

Answer (score 2):

Next highest:

```
 #  121 =>  180    -119 =>  -60
 #  120 =>  180    -120 =>  -60
 #  119 =>  120    -121 => -120

 $n - ($n % 60) + 60
```

Next largest:

```
 #  121 =>  180    -119 => -120
 #  120 =>  180    -120 => -180
 #  119 =>  120    -121 => -180

 $n + ( $n >= 0 ? +1 : -1 ) * ( 60 - (abs($n) % 60) )
```

`$n % 60 == 0` will tell you if $n is a multiple of 60.

Comment: I thought using `int` could interact with the rounding error from dividing by 60 to give the wrong answer, but I no longer believe so. What you have is fine.

Comment: In a lower-level language, my approach (3 integer operations) will be much faster than `int` or `ceil`, but that's mostly lost in noise with Perl.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiples of 60 to be unchanged:

```
use POSIX 'ceil';

my $next_multiple = ceil(($input/$constant)/60) * 60;
```

If you want multiples of 60 to be bumped up to the next multiple (as your existing code does):

```
use POSIX 'floor';

my $next_multiple = (1 + floor(($input/$constant)/60)) * 60;
```